# Scrollable check in useEffect does not work on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component where I'm displaying a list of items. The list can be scrollable depending on the number of items. I want to display left and right arrow buttons only if the list is scrollable in those directions.

To achieve this, I'm using a useEffect hook that checks if the list is scrollable and sets state variables accordingly. It works, however, when I refresh the page it no longer works, the arrows don't appear even when the list is scrollable. Here's my code:

```
const [isScrollableLeft, setIsScrollableLeft] = useState(false);
const [isScrollableRight, setIsScrollableRight] = useState(false);
const listRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    const checkScrollable = () => {
        if (listRef.current) {
            const { scrollLeft, scrollWidth, clientWidth } = listRef.current;
            setIsScrollableLeft(scrollLeft > 0);
            setIsScrollableRight(scrollWidth > clientWidth + scrollLeft);
        }
    };

    if (listRef.current) {
        listRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollable);
        // Initial check
        checkScrollable();
    }

    // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
        if (listRef.current) {
            listRef.current.removeEventListener("scroll", checkScrollable);
        }
    };
}, []);
```

And here's the JSX:

```
<div className="community-overall-link-container">
    {isScrollableLeft && <div className="link-container-arrow arrow-left-main" onClick={scrollToStart}><img src={leftDirection} alt="←" /></div>}
        <ul ref={listRef} className="community-links-container">
            <li className={`community-links-item ${communityLink === 1 ? 'community-links-item-active' : ''}`} onClick={() => setCommunityLink(1)}>Upcoming Hangout</li>
            <li className={`community-links-item ${communityLink === 2 ? 'community-links-item-active' : ''}`} onClick={() => setCommunityLink(2)}>Discussions</li>
            <li className={`community-links-item ${communityLink === 3 ? 'community-links-item-active' : ''}`} onClick={() => setCommunityLink(3)}>Organizers</li>
        </ul>
    {isScrollableRight && <div className="link-container-arrow arrow-right-main" onClick={scrollToEnd}><img src={rightDirection} alt="→" /></div>}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `checkScrollable` function inside a separate function and call it when the component is mounted by adding the function call inside the useEffect dependency array.
Without using the dependency array, when page refreshes the component may not have mounted yet and the initial useEffect doesn't get called. This could be why the state variables `isScrollableLeft` and `isScrollableRight` are not getting set.

```
const [isScrollableLeft, setIsScrollableLeft] = useState(false);
const [isScrollableRight, setIsScrollableRight] = useState(false);
const listRef = useRef();

const checkScrollable = () => {
  if (listRef.current) {
    const { scrollLeft, scrollWidth, clientWidth } = listRef.current;
    setIsScrollableLeft(scrollLeft > 0);
    setIsScrollableRight(scrollWidth > clientWidth + scrollLeft);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  // Run on initial mount
  checkScrollable();

  if (listRef.current) {
    listRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollable);
  }

  // Clean up the event listener when unmounted
  return () => {
    if (listRef.current) {
      listRef.current.removeEventListener("scroll", checkScrollable);
    }
  };
}, [checkScrollable]); // Call the function again on mount
```